# Queue of strings to single string

Tags: java

I'm somewhat new to programming, so sorry if this is stupid..

I have a Queue of strings, and I want to turn into a single, space-delimited string.

For example `{"a","b","c"}` should become `"a b c"`

How would I go about doing this? (I google searched this and didn't find much :/)

Comment: Can we see some sort of attempt?

Comment: why you need a queue? do you mean an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Queue", but I'll assume it is an array and base my answer off of that assumption.

In order to combine them, try doing this.

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String myNewString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
        myNewString += " " + myStringArray[i];
    } else {
        myNewString += myStringArray[i];
    }
}
```

Now, the value of `myNewString` is equal to `"a b c"`

EDIT:

In order to not use an `if` each loop, use this instead:

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String myNewString = myStringArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
    myNewString += " " + myStringArray[i];
}
```

Comment: How could you improve your solution so that the (an) `if` is only evaluated once?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Editted in a fix

Comment: That's it, but don't forget the space. And might want to check the size first, ideally.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You should be a CS teacher... :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `join` method of the Apache `StringUtils` class (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use basic logic as below:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String inStr : arrInData) {
    builder.append(inStr+" ");
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: You missed the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This code might not work, I did not test it, but you should understand the logic.

```
//This string is your queue
String[] strings = new String[];

//This is your finished String
String string = "";

for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    string = string + " " + strings[i];
}
```

Comment: Your code don't even compile.

Comment: Hah!  You're right, @Drogba.  I fixed four of the five errors but missed the first one.  Maybe you could fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strings = { "a", "b", "c" };
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  result += strings[i] + ((i < strings.length - 1) ? " " : "");
}
```

The result is `"a b c"`.